# Excel macros making all text superscript

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I have several different macros that create a sheet in Excel 2003 and populate it with information.  These macros are all written in VBA and some are linked to a toolbar in Excel and some are in MS Access.  The problem I have is that once the sheet is populated, all the text is superscript.  Since this happens with macros executed from Excel and Access, it makes me think there is some setting in Excel that is defaulting to superscript.  Has anyone ever seen a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen by default with the scenerio you describe. Can you check the vba code for any instance of this code segment: `.Subscript = True`? I suspect its setting it for "selection" and some code logic isn't turning it off.